# Im looking to patent a board game

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement

In reference to the patent: [US7255348](https://www.google.com/patents/US7255348)

I am also looking to patent a board game with an 8 sided board, but the game is seemingly of no similarity to mine, would the 8 sided board be an issue for me when trying to patent my game, when this one already has 8 sides.

Comment: I see 16 sides to the board in the patent.

Comment: Without knowing what your game is, this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

A claim is infringed if ALL the elements of that claim are met. As you implicitly note, there is far more to these claims then the number of sides of the board. Unless your game includes these other elements (and that's a potentially complex factual and legal question in and of itself).